# Custom inspector values in prefab mode not save to prefab

Tags: unity, prefabs

I have a prefab with a custom `GridModel` component which has a custom editor. For some reason whenever I edit a value in Prefab Mode, the value doesn't save in the prefab asset and vice versa. How can I fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
public class GridModel : MonoBehaviour, IGridModel
{
    public Vector2Int dimensions;
}
```

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(GridModel))]
public class GridModelEditor : Editor
{
    private GridModel gridModel;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        gridModel = (GridModel)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        gridModel.dimensions = EditorGUILayout.Vector2IntField("Size", gridModel.dimensions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call [`Undo.RecordObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo.RecordObject.html) to record the object before changing it, so the editor knows it has modifications that need saving. This also creates an "Undo" entry so the user can reverse the change if they need to.

As the doc linked above points out:

> Important: To correctly handle instances where `objectToUndo` is an instance of a Prefab, [`PrefabUtility.RecordPrefabInstancePropertyModifications`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.RecordPrefabInstancePropertyModifications.html) must be called after `RecordObject`.

You can also get these benefits automatically by making your changes through the `SerializedObject`/`SerializedProperty` API, which handles the necessary book-keeping and supports multi-object editing.

Comment: That seems to fix the saving from prefab mode to the prefab in the assets overview, but how do I make it that if I save the asset in the overview it also saves it in prefab mode?

Comment: I'd recommend using the SerializedObject approach then to get native handling of all the different editing scenarios together.